# How to make Time.now less precise?

Tags: ruby, rubymine

I simply want to return a less precise, truncated version of Time.now.

When I run `Time.now` I get a very precise object `2014-10-02 14:49:47 -0400tim`. I only want 
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:MM.

How can I (temporarily) cast the precision of a Time.now return object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[strftime()](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Time.html#method-i-strftime) allows you to provide a format string for your time object. A list of format flags can be found in the documentation

Example from Docs:

```
t = Time.new(2007,11,19,8,37,48,"-06:00") #=> 2007-11-19 08:37:48 -0600
t.strftime("Printed on %m/%d/%Y")   #=> "Printed on 11/19/2007"
t.strftime("at %I:%M%p")            #=> "at 08:37AM"
```

Your Example:

```
t.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %T")    #=> YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:MM.
```

Comment: @AdamJ Happy to help. If you feel this question has been answered, please mark it as such.

Comment: sorry got distracted!

Comment: It is unprofessional, in my opinion, to request that one's answer be selected, particularly after such a short period of time, as it may discourage other, possibly better, answers from being submitted.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new `Time` object that is the original time rounded to the nearest minute:

```
require 'time'

t = Time.now
  #=> 2014-10-02 12:40:22 -0700
new_time = t + (t.sec >= 30 ? 60-t.sec : -t.sec)
  #=> 2014-10-02 12:40:00 -0700

t += 30
  #=> 2014-10-02 12:40:52 -0700
new_time = t + (t.sec >= 30 ? 60-t.sec : -t.sec)
  #=> 2014-10-02 12:41:00 -0700
```